# What is the most optimal/intuitive way of expressing rotations: rotation matrices, euler angles or quaternions?

Tags: rotations, quaternions

If I understand correctly there are multiple ways of approaching rotations in space. On approach is the rotation matrix which is defined as:

$$ R = \begin{bmatrix}
\cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\  
\sin \theta & \cos \theta 
\end{bmatrix} $$

Another approach is are using euler angles and defined axes: $ \alpha, \beta, \gamma $

The third approach (and for me a bit more obscure) is quaternions. A rotation of angle $\theta$ around the axis defined by the unit vector $ \vec{u} = (u_x, u_y, u_z) = u_x\mathbf{i} + u_y\mathbf{j} + u_z\mathbf{k}$
can be represented by a quaternion. This can be done using:

$$ \mathbf{q} = e^{\frac{\theta}{2}{(u_x\mathbf{i} + u_y\mathbf{j} + u_z\mathbf{k})}} = \cos \frac{\theta}{2} + (u_x\mathbf{i} + u_y\mathbf{j} + u_z\mathbf{k}) \sin \frac{\theta}{2}$$

Are they exactly "mathematically" equivalent? It seems that an algebraic concept like quaternions that can represent rotations must be the best. Also it seems kind of coincidental that these objects can describe rotations that well. Apparantly it also doesn't give problems like a 'gimbal lock'.

The reason I am asking is because I am trying to write a python script in understanding mechanical motions better.

Comment: The OpenGL standard uses matrices to represent rotations and your graphics card is designed to calculate on those matrices directly. If they're better than quaternions or not is still debatable even if we've settled on a standard.

Comment: The rotation matrices you describe are only the 2D ones. The ones in 3D are, after a change in basis that depends on each matrix, basically a block diagonal matrix with a 2D rotation and a 1 in the corner (the Euler rotation theorem). Each formalism has pros and cons that make "optimal" dependent on context. And "intuitive" is a bit subjective, but for me quaternions are the most intuitive since (how I develop the formalism) they don't involve arbitrary coordinates. (But in real-world applications, we need coordinates of course.)